# Remove currency symbols and literals from a string with a price universal solution

Tags: python, regex, string, converters, currency

I have such examples:

> USD 10.99
>
> LIR10.99
>
> $ 10.99
>
> $10.99

So the input data may be any 'symbolfloat' or 'symbol float'.

I have made something like this:

```
float((str(param[2]).translate(None, '$USDLIR')))
```

But it can be any world currency, so it must be a universal converter.

Comment: remove everything before the first digit?

Comment: def price_convert(_price):
    return float(sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', _price))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove anything from the string which isn't a digit or a decimal point:

```
import re
import locale
decimal_point_char = locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']
clean = re.sub(r'[^0-9'+decimal_point_char+r']+', '', str(param[2]))
value = float(clean)
```

That will also handle grouping (`$ 1,000.00`) and different locales.

Comment: don't name a variable `input` please, that scares my cat.

Comment: Yeah, I know that Python has an `input()` function. But I also believe that I should be able to name my local variables as I see fit :-)

Comment: well, then better hope you never feel like to name your local variable `__builtins__` or the like ;)

Comment: This solution applies to OP's examples but hardly universal. Some countries use comma as decimal separator and dot as thousand separator.

Comment: @m_poorUser Good point. What do you think of my new solution?

Answer (score 10):

You can remove everything except the number (including comma or decimal dot):

```
import re
trim = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')
mystring = 'USD 10.99'
result = trim.sub('', mystring)
print(result)
# '10.99'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution:

```
def price_convert(_price):
    return float(sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', _price))
```

Comment: It's a good solution but keep in mind that wouldn't work if the price has a dot and a comma, i.e. $1.999,00

Answer (score 0):

based on the [first answer by @tiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27128417/4433157);
This figures out whether a comma or a dot is the decimal separator, and works with cases such as "USD $1.000,55" without a problem

```
# %%
import re

def price_to_float(price: str) -> float:
    # clean the price string
    trimmer = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')
    trimmed = trimmer.sub('', price)

    # figure out the separator which will always be "," or "." and at position -3 if it exists
    decimal_separator = trimmed[-3:][0]
    if decimal_separator not in [".", ","]:
        decimal_separator = None

    # re-clean now that we know which separator is the correct one
    trimer = re.compile(rf'[^\d{decimal_separator}]+')
    trimmed = trimer.sub('', price)

    if decimal_separator == ",":
        trimmed = trimmed.replace(",", ".")

    result = float(trimmed)
    return result

mystring = 'USD $1.000,55'
print(price_to_float(mystring))
# >> 1000.55
```