# How to prepare list of prices for sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have scraped a list of prices from a site that I want to get the average on. And correct me if I am wrong but my assumption is that the data needs to not have dollar signs to be a be added up to get the total sum so that it can be used to get the average price of the list.

My attempts include but are not limited to using a for loop to slice the 0 index off each list item.

```
for i in clean:
    i = i[1:]
```

i also originally tried just running it without creating a variable but it does literally nothing to the output of printing the clean list

```
for i in clean:
        i = i[1:]
```

example list of current list i have:

> clean = [$123.56, $234.56, $561.12]

What I would like the output of the cleaned up list to be:

> [123.56, 234.56, 561.12]

Comment: `[float(i[1:]) for i in clean]`?

Comment: Still outputs the same list with the $

Comment: Have you assigned it back? `clean = [float(i[1:]) for i in clean]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to use enumerate. Here is a very simple solution to your problem.

```
clean = ['$123.56', '$234.56', '$561.12']

result = []

for i in clean:
  result.append(float(i[1:]))

print(result) # [123.56, 234.56, 561.12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the library 're':

```
import re
trim = re.compile(r'[^\d.,]+')

my_string = '$12.56' #works also with USD or other currency, with space or not

result = trim.sub('',my_string)
print(result)

>>> 12.56
```

For a list:

```
my_list = ['$123.56', '$234.56', '$561.12']
list_without_currency = [float(trim.sub('',e)) for e in my_list]

>>> [123.56, 234.56, 561.12]
```

EDIT:

see also: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128253/remove-currency-symbols-and-literals-from-a-string-with-a-price-universal-soluti) (SO)

Comment: this will work to, I wanted to avoid regex as using slice is a faster method when getting into bigger datasets. this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-methods-to-remove-the-from-your-data-in-python-and-the-fastest-one-281489382455) is an interesting read on the fastest method of removing currency symbol