# How do I convert a list of currency strings into float in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
lst = ['$15,700.23', '3,000', '257.89', '19. 50', '$36.7', '36.2.13', 'abc23.50']
```

How do I convert it into a list of floats without the `'$'`, `','`and whitespace,if it contains anyother special symbols(or like '36.2.13') delete it from the list.
So the output should be:

```
new_lst = [15700.23, 3000.00, 257.89, 19.50, 36.70]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128253/remove-currency-symbols-and-literals-from-a-string-with-a-price-universal-soluti) seems a duplicate

Comment: In your own words, what would you need to do to sanitize `"'$15,700.23'"` so that it can be converted to a `float`? What about `'19. 50'`? And what happens when you try to convert something that _won't_ be sanitized by those rules? How can you prevent that from stopping your program?

Answer (score 0):

just fix the string like that:

```
strings = [w.replace('$',"").replace(',',"").replace(" ","") for w in lst]

def is_floatable(strng):
   try:
      float(strng)
      return True
   except:
      return False

new_lst = [float(w) for w in strings if is_floatable(w)]
```

Comment: The idea is right, but the execution isn't quite there. This breaks on multiple of OP's example inputs

Comment: fixed it, was a typo….

Comment: Nope, `"19. 50"`  fails, as does `"36.2.13"` and `"abc23.50"`

Comment: ok ok… was writing it trough my phone, took time…

Comment: uuuuggghhh fixed it

Comment: `import Counter` seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

you can first use regexp to locate the last period code, and then use `str.isdigit()` to eliminate irrelevant characters. See if this matches your expectations.

```
import re

lst = ['$15,700.23', '3,000', '257.89', '19. 50', '$36.7', '36.2.13', 'abc23.50']

def clean_number(s):
    if '.' in s:
        ints,decimals = re.match('(.+)\.(.+)',s).groups()
    else:
        ints = s
        decimals = '0'
    int_part = ''.join((s for s in ints if s.isdigit()))
    decimal_part = ''.join((s for s in decimals if s.isdigit()))
    return float(f'{int_part}.{decimal_part}')

list_cleaned = [clean_number(s) for s in lst]
print(list_cleaned)
```