# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$50.50'

Tags: python, function, floating-point, type-conversion, calculator

I have this python function here. However when running I'm getting an error "could not convert string to float: '$50.50'". I need to add the input as a string including the "$" sign and then convert it to a float number in the backend. The function seems to work adding only "50.50" as input.

```
def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    tip = dollars * percent/100
    print(f"Leave $" , str(tip) )

def dollars_to_float(d):
    str.lstrip(d)
    return float(d)

def percent_to_float(p):
    str.rstrip(p)
    return float(p)
    
main()
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/nelsonlamounier/indoor/indoor.py", line 13, in <module>
main()

File "/Users/nelsonlamounier/indoor/indoor.py", line 9, in dollars_to_float
return float(d)

File "/Users/nelsonlamounier/indoor/indoor.py", line 9, in dollars_to_float
return float(d)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$50.50'
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) You could check if `$` is prepended and give "float" a substring without it.

Comment: Also the `lstrip` and `rstrip` only remove whitespaces. What you want to use is string slicing like `return float(d[1:])` and `return float(p[:-1])`. These get rid of the first and last characters respectively.

Comment: @LTJ lstrip and rstrip are not limited to stripping of whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove $ before number like:

```
def dollars_to_float(d):
  str.lstrip(d)
  return float(d.replace("$",""))
```

Comment: this function won't work for floats nor integers or strings of numbers with commas like `'$5,000'`

Answer (score 1):

For a more general case, update `dollars_to_float` with the following:

```py
def dollars_to_float(d):
    d = ''.join([ch for ch in d if ch.isnumeric() or ch == '.'])
    return float(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is error prone, as a single space character would already be able to break it. A more robust version of the currency to float conversion can be found here [Remove currency symbols and literals from a string with a price universal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128253/remove-currency-symbols-and-literals-from-a-string-with-a-price-universal-soluti)

You use locale to see what is the decimal point character (, or .), and regex to remove all characters other than numerals and the decimal point.

```
import re
import locale

def dollars_to_float(price_string: str) -> float:
  decimal_point_char = locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']
  clean = re.sub(r'[^0-9'+decimal_point_char+r']+', '', str(price_string))
  return float(clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove specific characters from the beginning or end of a string then use *strip()*

In this case your dollars_to_float and percent_to_float could be generalised to:

```
def to_float(d):
  return float(d.strip('$%'))
```

This has the advantage of supporting the $ and % characters at either the beginning or end of the string.

However, say the input is like this '$1,200'

That's going to fail due to the thousands separator. Also, why limit functionality to just dollars. Why not allow for an arbitrary preamble to the input string - e.g., USD1,200 or £1,234,50

Here's a reasonably robust approach to this problem.

```
import re
from locale import LC_NUMERIC, setlocale, localeconv

class CC:
    dp = None
    def __init__(self):
        if CC.dp is None:
            setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '')
            dp = localeconv()['decimal_point']
            CC.dp = f'[^0-9{dp}+-]+'
    def conv(self, s):
        return float(re.sub(CC.dp, '', s))

print(CC().conv('$1,200.5'))
print(CC().conv('£1,200'))
print(CC().conv('EUR1234.5'))
print(CC().conv('6543.21'))
```

**Output:**

```
1200.5
1200.0
1234.5
6543.21
```